# Apollo Grapql Refresh Token swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to build network layer using Apollo, and got one problem. I'm using [tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/networking/request-pipeline) from Apollo docs to refresh tokens. And they said that I should provide interceptor to handle token expired date. I did it. But I should create network request to refresh token, and this request catch by interceptor too. How I can resolve it?

```
class NetworkInterceptorProvider: DefaultInterceptorProvider {
override func interceptors<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(for operation: Operation) -> [ApolloInterceptor] {
    var interceptors = super.interceptors(for: operation)
    interceptors.insert(UserManagementInterceptor(), at: 0)
    return interceptors
}
```

My UserManagementInterceptor:

```
 func interceptAsync<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(
    chain: RequestChain,
    request: HTTPRequest<Operation>,
    response: HTTPResponse<Operation>?,
    completion: @escaping (Result<GraphQLResult<Operation.Data>, Error>) -> Void
) {
    guard let token = AuthenticationService.shared.getAccessToken() else {
        chain.handleErrorAsync(
            UserError.noUserLoggedIn,
            request: request,
            response: response,
            completion: completion
        )
        AuthenticationService.shared.status = .unauthenticated
        print("No access token")
        return
    }
    if AuthenticationService.shared.checkTokenExpired() {
        print("Token expired")
        guard let refreshToken = AuthenticationService.shared.getRefreshToken() else {
            AuthenticationService.shared.status = .unauthenticated
            print("No refresh token")
            return
        }
        NetworkManager.shared.apollo.perform(mutation: Network.RefreshTokenMutation(token: refreshToken)) { [weak self] tokenRenewResult in
            guard let self else { return }
            switch tokenRenewResult {
            case .failure:
                AuthenticationService.shared.status = .unauthenticated
                print("Filed request")
                break
            case let .success(token):
```

As result I've got recursion with "Token expired", because my network request **RefreshTokenMutation** passed through this interceptor too... How I can create exception for token refresh network method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
 class NetworkInterceptorProvider: DefaultInterceptorProvider {
        override func interceptors<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(for operation: Operation) -> [ApolloInterceptor] {
            var interceptors = super.interceptors(for: operation)
            if checkIsAuthorizationRequired(for: operation) {} else {
                interceptors.insert(UserManagementInterceptor(), at: 0)
            }
            return interceptors
        }
    
        func checkIsAuthorizationRequired<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(for _: Operation) -> Bool {
            let authLoginOperation = Operation.operationName == "AuthLoginMutation"
            let refreshTokenOperation = Operation.operationName == "RefreshToken"
            let signUp = Operation.operationName == "AuthSignUp"
            if authLoginOperation || refreshTokenOperation || signUp {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
```